# How to generate a chart using Laravel?

Tags: charts, laravel, laravel-3

I'm working with Laravel 3. I want to make a reporting page on the website. 
I have some view table as per below:

```
+---------+-----------------+-------+
| user_id | username        | total |
+---------+-----------------+-------+
|       1 | user            |    12 |
|       2 | admin           |     3 |
|       3 | user2           |     1 |
|       4 | user3           |     1 |
+---------+-----------------+-------+
```

I want to show the data in chart view. What is the best way to make it?

Comment: Laravel doesn't provides such functionality out of box, you will need to look for a third party solution for that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I second [phpChart](http://phpChart.org). Used it in the past for an online report task. Very easy to create charts quickly.

Here's the solution to your scenario using [phpChart](http://phpChart.org) based on their [online example](http://phpchart.org/examples/complete-phpchart-examples/) -- [Axis Labels Rotated Text 2](http://phpchart.org/phpChart/examples/axis_labels_rotated_text_2.php):

```
<?php 
$line = array(array('user', 12), array('admin', 3), array('user2', 1), array('user3', 1));

$pc = new C_PhpChartX(array($line),'user_chart');
$pc->add_plugins(array('canvasTextRenderer'));
//set series
$pc->add_series(array('renderer'=>'plugin::BarRenderer'));
//set axes
$pc->set_axes(array(
    'xaxis'  => array(
        'renderer'=>'plugin::CategoryAxisRenderer',
        'tickRenderer'=>'plugin::CanvasAxisTickRenderer'),
    'yaxis'  => array(
        'autoscale'=>true,
        'tickRenderer'=>'plugin::CanvasAxisTickRenderer')
));

$pc->draw(800,500);
?>
```

Result:
[image]

Change the 6th line to PieRenderer you will get a pie chart.

```
<?php
$line = array(array('user', 12), array('admin', 3), array('user2', 1), array('user3', 1));

$pc = new C_PhpChartX(array($line),'chart_1');
$pc->add_plugins(array('canvasTextRenderer'));
//set series
$pc->add_series(array('renderer'=>'plugin::PieRenderer'));
//set axes
$pc->set_series_default(array(
    'renderer'=>'plugin::PieRenderer',
    'rendererOptions'=>array('showDataLabels'=>true)));
$pc->set_legend(array('show'=>true,
    'rendererOptions'=> array('numberRows'=> 1),
    'location'=> 's'));

$pc->draw(800,500);
?>
```

[image]

Here's a great intro on Codeproject I found:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/604542/Creating-Interactive-HTML5-Graphs-in-PHP

Answer (score 5):

Laravel doesn't provides any charting library out of the box. You need to find a third party library written in PHP to generate charts from your Laravel app.

Some free library for charting are:

- [pChart - A PHP class to build charts](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/). Sample chart shown below:

  [image: Sample chart generated by pChart]
- [phpCHART - Make HTML5 Charts in PHP](http://phpchart.net/). Sample chart shown below:

  [image: Sample chart generated by phpCHART]

I strongly encourage you to [search for php charting library](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20chart) here in StackOverflow to see the opinion from other experienced users.

When choosing a particular library add it to you `composer.json` file as any other dependency.